# How to do a relative import of file within a folder in the parent directory in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, python-import

I have a filesystem that looks roughly like this:

```
> unit-testing
   __init__.py
   > hardware
      __init__.py
      test_All.py
   > tests
      __init__.py
      scc.py
```

I am attempting to import `scc.py` into the `test_ALL.py` file, like this:

```
from ..tests import scc
```

This results in the following error:

```
"ValueError: attempted relative import beyond top-level package"
```

This is surprising, because [this part of the Python 3.7.1 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#intra-package-references) has this example with the same syntax as my code:

```
from ..filters import equalizer
```

So I'm not sure why this error is happening or what it even means. Any suggestions?